# how to Parse item and subitem in xml parsing

Tags: java, android

```
<taxmann>
    <docdetails>
    <info id="104010000000007617" date="19780225">
    <physicalpath>\\192.168.1.102\CMS\DATA</physicalpath>
    <filepath isxml="N">
    \NOTIFICATIONS\DIRECTTAXLAWS\HTMLFILES\150025021978.htm
    </filepath>
    <summary></summary>
    <description></description>
    <heading>
    2187 [S.O.1500] | Section 35(1)(ii) of the Income-tax Act, 1961 - Scientific research expenditure - Approved scientific research associations/institutions
    </heading>
    <correspondingcitation/>
    <hasfile>YES</hasfile>
    <sortby>20120328160152743</sortby>
    <parentid></parentid>
    <parentchapterid></parentchapterid>
    </info>
    </docdetails>
</taxmann>
```

Code:

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_DOCDETAILS);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            map.put(KEY_HEADING, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HEADING));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);


       }
```

This is My Xml Format i want to xmlParse  and want to dsiaply id,date,heading  i m able to display heading But i am not to print  date and id can u please tell me how i will implemnt it . this is my code to Print heading please modify my code and Print heading ,id,date..

Comment: Please see this: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Comment: can u add me on code that logic please coz i m trying much not able to do this i did this example already but not able to  Understood

Comment: http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetNotificationList?YearID=&CircularNo=33&SearchText=tax&pagenumber=1

Comment: this is my Url PLEASE TELL ME NOW

Answer (score 1):

1.Declaration

```
      String URL = "http://www.google.co.in/ig/api?news&hl=en";
      String KEY_ITEM = "news"; 
      String KEY_ID = "news_entry";
      String KEY_NAME = "title";
      String KEY_COST = "url";
      String KEY_DESC = "snippet";
```

2.Parsing

```
 XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
 String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
 Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
 NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
   for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
     NamedNodeMap attributes = e.getAttributes();
    System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes.getLength());
     for (int a = 0; a < attributes.getLength(); a++) 
     {
             Node theAttribute = attributes.item(a);
             System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());
     }
         NodeList nl1=e.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
     System.out.println("keyId"+nl1.getLength());
     for(int j=0;j<nl1.getLength();j++)
     {
         Element e1 = (Element) nl1.item(j);

         NodeList n = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_NAME);

          for (int k = 0; k < n.getLength(); k++) {

              Element e2 = (Element) n.item(k);
        //  System.out.println("node Title value"+e2.getNodeName());
             NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
            // System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
             for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
             {
                     Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                     System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

             }
          }

          NodeList n1 = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COST);
        // System.out.println("title "+n.getLength());
          for (int k = 0; k < n1.getLength(); k++) {

              Element e2 = (Element) n1.item(k);
        //    System.out.println("node Url value");
             NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
          //   System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
             for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
             {
                     Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                     System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

             }}

             NodeList n2 = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_DESC);
            // System.out.println("title "+n.getLength());
              for (int k = 0; k < n2.getLength(); k++) {

                  Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(k);
            //    System.out.println("node snippet value"+e2.getNodeName());
                 NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
              //   System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
                 for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
                 {
                         Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                         System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

                 }
              }  

     }

//    menuItems.add(map);
}
```

Comment: try it ,it is parsing of other xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
     NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("info");

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
     NamedNodeMap attributes = e.getAttributes();

        for (int a = 0; a < attributes.getLength(); a++) 
        {
                Node theAttribute = attributes.item(a);
                System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry,i can't parse your xml because it gives response code 500,i think it have some restrication from server.

Comment: but i have parse other xml for you,that fulfill your requirements.